# Case Class with higher order function in Parameter

Tags: scala

Suppose Case Class which takes higher order function in parameters. eg.

```
case class CC(a: String = "1",b: Int => Int,c : Int = 0,d: Boolean = false)
val v = 3
val rc = CC ("1",v => v+v,0,true) //rc: CC = CC(1,A$A161$A$A161$$Lambda$1856/1364270469@44fc4b1b,0,true)
```

Why scala gives the class rather associate Int value to "b"?

Comment: `val v = 3` is unrelated to `v => v+v`. The two have nothing to do with each other. It would be exactly the same if you'd used `x => x+x`. `b` isn't an `Int`. It is a lambda, an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the second line in your code (`val v = 3`) is not used. The second parameter to your case class is defined in the first line of your code to be a function that takes an `Int` and gives back an `Int`. In the third line, you instantiate an instance of CC by correctly passing such a function: `v => v + v` as the parameter `b`.

When the REPL displays an instance of CC to you it shows you a class that corresponds to the anonymous function you passed as `b`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `v` in your function defintion is unrelated to the assigned val `v`.  Maybe the following example would help clarify:

```
case class CC(a: String = "1", b: Int => Int, c : Int = 0, d: Boolean = false)
val v = 3

// `v` below is unrelated to the assigned val `v`
val rc = CC ("1", v => v + v, 0, true)
rc.b(1)
// res1: Int = 2

// `v` below is the assigned val `v`
val rc = CC ("1", x => x + v, 0, true)
rc.b(1)
// res2: Int = 4
```